# Can [面倒]{めんどう} be used as "boring"?

Tags: translation, idioms, word-usage

I've just heard many times [面倒]{めんどう} in anime, in translation is not troublesome but boring. Is it usual? Which is more appropriate?

Example: 面倒な仕事です。

Comment: You can consult a dictionary: http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%9D%A2%E5%80%92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary meaning of 面倒な/面倒くさい is "bothersome", "time-consuming", or "annoying". The phrase "boring job" usually corresponds to 退屈【たいくつ】な仕事, 面白【おもしろ】くない仕事 or つまらない仕事.

So I basically agree that translating 面倒 as "boring" is not very literal. But there are times when translators intentionally avoid literal translations for various reasons. I can't say whether "boring" was inappropriate or not without actually seeing that anime.

Comment: Translation is so hard to do. Assuming the context of a 'robot' saying this, it's a valid translation.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that "面倒" implies boring.
However, You should not translate "面倒" into "boring".

"面倒" ordinary means that the problem has a little difficulty for the speaker.
ex.

> 君には面倒をかけてしまった

this sentence doesn't mean that the speaker made the other boring,
but means that the speaker gave the other trouble.

Comment: I would say that if you really want to convey "boring", you should use　面倒くさい, which is more explicit.